# NHibernate Evict - EntityKeys is readonly so object won't evict

Tags: nhibernate, evict

A vendor supplied code using NHibernate... and I'm not familiar at all with NHibernate.  At one point in the code, it is calling the Flush() and it is throwing an error because one of the entities has a 1/1/0001 for a date value.  I attempted to circumvent by evicting any entities that have that as a value.  However, the evict is not working as the EntityKeys is set to Read-Only.

Code:

```
if (((Event)e.Identifier).EnrollmentDate == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    Db.CurrentSession.Evict(e.Identifier);
}
```

I also attempted:

```
 Db.CurrentSession.Evict(typeof(Event));
```

Whenever the code executed, it didn't throw any errors, but it didn't evict either.  When I tried the RemoveAt, it threw the 'Collection is read-only.' error

Is there a way around that?

Comment: I had to add a line to explicity load the entity.  After that, it allowed it to be evicted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the problem with the date being set to an invalid value. Attempting to work around the problem is a losing proposition.

Comment: I agree it is a data issue and this isn't addressing the root cause.  But, the vendor won't allow the property to be changed to a nullable date so evicting the object is my only option.

Comment: Can you set the date to a valid value? Or use a "magic number" date that is valid for the database?